# Hanesomtable Data not showing in grid

Tags: model-view-controller, handsontable

I recently found out that Handsome made a critical change in how you use calls like
"Handsontable.Dom.addEvent". I happen to stumble across a statement that said Handsome change the format to "Handsontable.dom.addEvent". Just the change from "Dom" to "dom" made it start working.
Now I am having another problem. The "Load" event goes to the controller and executes the "GetCar" routine. I can see the Row Data in the "return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);".
The grid does switch from one row to six rows but none of the data is displayed. It does display "Data Loaded", so this tells me the "success" function is working.
success: function (data) {

```
                //alert(data);
                debugger;
                hot.loadData(data);
                exampleConsole.innerHTML = 'Data loaded';
            }
```

Tried changing "hot.LoadData(data)" to "hot.Loaddata(data)" but that creates an error, so they did not change that bit of code.   Also tried var resultdata = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
hot.loadData(resultdata);  with same result

Comment: Can you share the rest of the code? The `instance.loadData(your_dataset)` is the correct way to execute data upload and it does not require any additional rendering. Maybe in your case 'data' is the dataset that you already use? You can check what is going on by adding the `afterChange` hook to load the changes for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. The demo is now working and I am now onto modifications. The demo routine will be the base for the program I am writing. Thanks all for the help.